Discord.js creating channel within category
const guild = interaction.guild; const user = interaction.user; const ticketChannelName = ticket-${user.username}`
// create category if not exits
const category = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == 'TICKETS' && c.type == ChannelType.GuildCategory);
console.log()
    if(!category) {
        await interaction.guild.channels.create({
            name: 'TICKETS', // The name given to the Channel by the user
            type: ChannelType.GuildCategory, // The type of the Channel created.
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], // The permissions of the Channel created.
            
        });
    }
    
    else{
        
    }


    
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == {ticketChannelName} && c.type == ChannelType.GuildText);

    if(channel) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Hata!')
        .setDescription('Zaten bir ticket oluşturmuşsunuz.')
        .setColor(Colors.Red)
        .setTimestamp();

        return await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true});
    }

    else{
        await interaction.guild.channels.create({
        parent: category, // The category of the Channel created.
        name: ticketChannelName, // The name given to the Channel by the user
        type: ChannelType.GuildText, // The type of the Channel created.
        
    });
    }
}

}`
I want to create a channel within category but i cant, the channel is creating but not within category.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Try putting category channel id instead of constant variable.
await interaction.guild.channels.create({
    parent: category.id, //here
    name: ticketChannelName,
    type: ChannelType.GuildText, 
});


You can check out the guide in the official discord.js docs categoryObject.parent
await interaction.guild.channels.create({
    parent: category.parent, //here
    name: ticketChannelName,
    type: ChannelType.GuildText, 
});

